# how do I select records from a layer that do NOT have features from another layer within them?

Tags: select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I'm trying to find vacant land in my city. I have a layer with buildings and a layer of parcels. I want to create a layer of the parcels that do not have buildings within them. I have tried select by location, but it only gives me parcels that do have buildings. Also, I have at least 80,000 buildings so each time I try a join it takes forever and usually crashes.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. Also include which software you want to or can use. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37406/select-by-not-in-location/37409#37409 Your question sounds very similar.

Comment: What GIS Software?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm currently running select by location, with parcels as my target layer and buildings as my source layer. I used the method "contain the source layer feature". Then I'll switch the selection. I think that should get me what I want; it's been running for about 10 minutes so far. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using ArcGIS. If your selection gives you all parcels that do have buildings, then you can simply press the "switch selection" button in the attribute table.

[image]

Note that the answer in the linked "similar question" doesn't provide any details as to how to go about reversing the selection.

Comment: Good point, I assumed a certain level of familiarity with the UI and interface in ArcMap when I answered that question. I will update it to include more detail.